# Can't connect to SQL Server database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I've installed and reinstalled SQL Server 2014 Express and Visual Studio, still it won't let me connect to a database. It won't even let me create a database.

Here is a the error message:

> The Data Source value in the connection string specifies an instance of SQL Server that is not installed. To resolve this issue, you can either choose to install the matching instance of SQL Server or modify the Data Source value in the connection string.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Posting images of errors, code, or sample data instead of the actual text is considered very rude here.

Comment: Also: what connection string are you using?

Comment: So, the error message is already stated clearly that you haven't installed SQL server on that computer.

Comment: **What exactly** are you installing? From which file?? Are you really installing the actual SQL Server database engine - or possibly just the Management Studio? (we've had several cases of people installing only the Mgmt Studio and not being able to connect to the server after that.....)

Comment: marc- it says microsoft SQL server 2014 express with managment tools

Answer (score 1):

Check on your SQL configuration manager if TCP/IP protocol is enabled for all ports, default is 1433.

Comment: I do apologize, Im completely new to SQL. How do i get to the configuration manager?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 Express is going to install itself with an instance name. You'll need to use something like this for your connection string (note the `myInstanceName`):

```
Server=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: That's the *default* that SQL Server Express uses - but it can be changed at the time of installation. SQL Server **Express** doesn't *have to* be installed as `.\SQLEXPRESS` ...

Answer (score 0):

So I went in and manually removed everything relating to SQL off my machine and then redownloaded and reinstalled it. and it seems that configuration manager was not installing in my previous tries. I also made sure that i set everything to its defaults, and it worked! I now have config manager and it connects to the databases now. Not sure why the last 2 times in installed it, it didnt work right but oh well. Its good now.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running Window 8 You can get to

1. Start > Run > SQLServerManager11.msc

or 
 2 . If you are using window 7 see this answer
     [Launch SQL Server on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199135/launch-sql-server-on-windows-7)

[image]